# Mock subprocess.Popen with dictionary as stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a function

```
def execute(process: subprocess.Popen):
    if not isinstance(process, subprocess.Popen):
        raise ValueError('expected: subprocessPopen, found: %s' % type(process))

    data = io.TextIOWrapper(process.stdout, encoding='utf-8')
    func1(data_input)
```

I want to unit test it, where I want `data` as a `dictionary` which is to be passed to `func1` as an argument but not able to find a way out.

Comment: Use `mock` library. What exactly you want to mock? `persist_lines` or `subprocess.Popen`?

Comment: I tried mocking it, but I didn't get the expected result as the io.TextIOWrapper(without mocking) function should also return a dictionary which takes process.stdout with encoding as 'utf-8'

Comment: @moooeeeep No, I didn't, could you please give me a hint on this.

Comment: After reading your post a second time, I don't really understand what the problem is. `TextIOWrapper()` returns no dictionary, and if `data_input` is required to be one, you should maybe work on that first?

Comment: @moooeeeep first of all I dont want to mock io.TextIOWrapper, but if we mock the subprocess.Popen than how do we do it so that the isinstance method doen't throw a error. Second what should I pass to io.TextIOWrapper as its first argument so that it give me a list or a dictionary without using .read() on io.TextIoWrapper object? Thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `spec` argument to the Mock object, in order to make it pass the *isinstance()* test:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock

Have a look at the `patch` decorator for how to replace the `process.stdout` member with, e.g., a `io.BytesIO` object:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch

You also might want to consider the examples given here:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but could you please help me find out what exactly I should pass in io.TextIOWrapper that should return me a list instead of a io.textiowrapper object ?

Comment: @SayedAweshRahman My first attempt would be to try calling the `readlines()` method. Other than that, maybe you don't need it. Can't you call `process.stdout.readlines()` directly?

Comment: No thats how its written, cant change the actual code to fix the test.

Comment: The thing is, `io.TextIOWrapper()` is a constructor that will always return the same object type. You can't somehow get a list out of it. The only thing I think you may (or may not) need would be something like this: `TextIOWrapper(BytesIO("Hello\nWorld".encode("utf-8")))` to mock the processes output to stdout.

Comment: That is so dumb of me. Finally, I got my ans.

Answer (score 0):

```
import mock

def test_run_func():
    subprocess.Popen = mock.MagicMock(return_value=expected_return_value)
    # The rest of your test...
```

Something like should work.